# PHP 8.1 Enum in laravel Enum case type int does not match enum backing type string

Tags: php, laravel, enums

I'm working in a Laravel 9 project, I have an Enum file called `LoanPurpose` and my loan purposes are integers. I'm storing these in my database as integers as this is what's required.

I now want to map them to a custom string to output to the view, but when I attempt to map them I get:

> Enum case type int does not match enum backing type string

What am I missing?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Enums\Applications\GB\Payday;

enum LoanPurpose: String
{
    case OTHER = 0;
    case GROCERIES = 1;

    public function label()
    {
        return match($this) {
            self::OTHER => 'Other',
            self::GROCERIES => 'Groceries'
        };
    }
}
```

- 0 should be mapped to "Other"
- 1 should be mapped to "Groceries"

Comment: My mistake, I've got `: String` after the enum.

Answer (score 1):

Your backed enums values are all **Int**, but the type declaration in the enum definition is **String**

```php
enum LoanPurpose: int
{
    case OTHER = 0;
    case GROCERIES = 1;

    public function label()
    {
        return match($this) {
            self::OTHER => 'Other',
            self::GROCERIES => 'Groceries'
        };
    }
}
$LoanPurpose = LoanPurpose::OTHER;
echo $LoanPurpose->label();//returns Other
```

> Note the type declaration in the enum definition. It indicates that
> all enum values are of a given type. You could also make it an int.
> Take note that only int and string are allowed as enum values.
>
> If you decide to assign enum values, all cases should have a value.
> You cannot mix and match them.